external HD RAW, then what?
Argh. It is one of these bad days really.
I had my work archive external 6tb HD attached on my main computer
(no bootable system on it)
I don't really know what happened, but when I put it back on, the disk was shown as RAW.
So, I reassigned a new drive letter, nothing happened.
Then I reduced the size of the drive of few Mo.
It did the trick, I have all the folders back inside the HD.
But within the retrieved folders, most of them (90%) do not contain anything inside, no files, no folders... but there are supposed to!
I ran testDisk, and it says Hard Disk too small...
I freaked out, so I stopped the process there
CristalDisk says it's GOOD
I am now running chkdsk /r (gonna take 10+ hours)
When I check dskmgmt, it says 660Gb left out of 6Tb, which is about right, I remember that much left before the trouble happened, therefore I assume, it is somewhere on the drive, just not visible
I am waiting the result of chkdsk, but I would like to know if there is something I can do

I wish I had better news to share, but every action you have taken, is probably the worst actions you could have taken. If this data is vital, you should immediately create a clone of the disk, and send the original to a professional data recovery service. chkdsk will verify the integrity of the file system which is obviously not positive if the entire file system was lost, because it at one point was being detected as a raw partition without one. Unfortunately, whatever damage chkdsk has done, cannot be reversed.

how do you clone the disk? in the past I used Carbon Copy Cloner, but I think that was on Mac. Can I stop the chkdsk now? it was just checking the bad clusters, so maybe not too late?
